# Is create_table in rails migrations a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

When I generate a model:

```
rails g model Post title content favorite:boolean
```

Rails creates a migration file that looks like this:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :content
      t.boolean :favorite

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

There's this `create_table(:posts)` that I've always wondered about which looks and behaves like a loop.  But I haven't found anything in the ruby language that mentions a loop that looks anything like this:

```
create_table() do
  # ...
end
```

I've found each loops, times loops, while loops, etc...and many other loops but I have never seen this loop or any loop that looks similar in the actual Ruby language.  Is this actually a part of the Ruby language that I overlooked or is this a creation made by ActiveRecord and/or Rails?  And if such a loop like this was created and is not built in, how did they do this (ie: how is it possible to create custom loops that look like this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a loop. [create_table](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table) is just a **method** from the [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements) class.

From the [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table):

> There are two ways to work with create_table. You can use the block
>   form or the regular form.

The following is just the ***block form*** of using `create_table` method where you can pass a block to it:

```
create_table(:table_name) do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I get it...Something like this: [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm).  I've never used this feature of ruby and wasn't even aware of it.  Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rails thing not ruby. You do have more similar syntax in rails.

You can use `link_to`, `form_for` in similar way.

Everything which have some do and object, seems like a loop syntax.

link_to syntax here :

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

form_for syntax here :

```
<%= form_for :person do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```